# Using elastic search to build flow/funnel results based on unique identifiers

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to be able to return a set of counts of individual documents from a single index based on a previous set of results, and am wondering if there is a way to do it without running a separate query for each.

So, given a data set like this (simplified version of my ES documents):

```
{
  "name": "visit",
  "sessionId": "session1"
},
{
  "name": "visit",
  "sessionId": "session2"
},
{
  "name": "visit",
  "sessionId": "session3"
},
{
  "name": "click",
  "sessionId": "session1"
},
{
  "name": "click",
  "sessionId": "session3"
}
```

What I would like to do is be able to search for `name: visit` and give a count of all those. That part is easy. But I would also like to be able to now count my `name: click` docs that have the `sessionId` of the `name: visit` result set and return a count of how many of those `name: click` there were as well as the `name: visit`.

Is there an easy way to do this? I have looked at aggregation APIs but they all seem to not quite fit my needs. There also seems to be a parent/child relationship but it doesn't apply to my situation since both documents I want to individually get counts of are of the same type.

Expected result would be something like this:

```
{
    "count": {
        // total number of visit events since this is my start point
        "visit": 3, 

        // the amount of click results that have sessionId 
        // matching my previous search's sessionId values
        "click": 2 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show what results you'd expect with the sample data you've shown above?

Comment: @Val definitely, added to my original post!

Comment: At first glance, you need to do this in two queries, the first aggregation query to retrieve the sessionIds and then a second aggregation query filtered with those sessionIds to find the count of clicks. It's not a big deal to run those two queries.

Comment: Sounds good then. If you make your comment an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, you need to do this in two queries:

1. the first aggregation query to retrieve the sessionIds and
2. a second aggregation query filtered with those sessionIds to find the count of clicks.

I don't think it's a big deal to run those two queries, but that depends on how much data you have and how many sessionIds you want to retrieve at once.